# Alphabet Puzzle

Tags: pattern

There is  a letter leaving two letters of the alphabet in order, after the letters placed at odd-numbered positions and leaving one letter of the alphabet in order after the placed at the  even-numbered positions.

1. ADFIKN
2. BEGJLN
3. CFHKLO
4. DFIKNP

I need help in understanding this puzzle and in solving it. I have to choose an option which satisfies the given condition in the question.

Comment: Answer is ADFIKN. A(2)D(1)F(2)I(1)K(2)N. here 2 means 2 letter's space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> **ADFIKN**

as

```
A(BC)D(E)F(GH)I(J)K(LM)N
   2   1    2   1    2
```